# How to fix a conditional problem in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using a condition such that if activeCardId is null nothing returns otherwise it would return something.It is working fine for all values except 0. It is returning nothing when value is 0.

I think it's related to 0 and null.

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    activeCardId: null 
  }
}

return(
  {this.state.activeCardId && ( // some random output...)
```

As this statement means if activecardId is not null then return some random output and return nothing if activecardId is null.

Comment: try 
this.state.activeCardId !== null ? return something : return null
it will work on 0 also as it will check if the value is null or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because, you are using `logical AND (&&)`.

`0` means falsy value, and logical AND dosen't return anything for false values, you should try this

```
{this.state.activeCardId !==null && ( // some random output...) }
```

Answer (score 0):

0 is a falsy value so

```
this.state.activeCardId
```

becomes false

Answer (score 0):

this would do the job:

```
return(
      {this.state.activeCardId!==null && ( // some random output...)
```

there is difference between null and 0 ,
0 is a value, 0 is also falsy in boolean statement
while null represents the intentional absence of any object value.

taken from : [MDN Null-javascript](http://null%20represents%20the%20intentional%20absence%20of%20any%20object%20value)